# Quire API seems to lack functionality to add tasks into boards and board columns

Tags: quire-api

Quire how to add a task to a board  and a board column with your API, i can manage to create tasks but can't assign them to a board with your API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add a task to an existing board set the `board` property of the [`PUT /task/{oid}`](https://quire.io/dev/api/#operation--task--oid--put) action

to add a column use the `addColumn` property of the [`PUT /board/{oid}`](https://quire.io/dev/api/#operation--board--oid--put) action

**UPDATE:**

to place a task into a specific board column you have to set the task status corresponding to the column `value` (e.g `{"status": 10}`) [`PUT /task/{oid}`](https://quire.io/dev/api/#operation--task--oid--put)

The task will then 'jump' into the matching column of your board

Comment: i need to assign a task to a column, not to create a new column, thanks

Comment: ah seems I misread your question as 2 separate questions ;)
"how to add a task to a board" and "add a column to a board"

The task status and the board column are  linked by status.

Did you try updating the the task and setting the task-status matching the column-value?